# Is there a way to enforce a size limit of MemoryCache in System.Runtime.Caching?

Tags: caching, .net-4.0

I'm using .net 4 Memory Cache. I would like to limit the size of the cache say to 10mb because I don't want my application to be abusing what goes in there.

I would also like to know how much memory my cache is at any given time. How can I tell at run time?

Answer (score 46):

You can specify the maximum amount of physical memory dedicated to the `MemoryCache` in the application config file using the [namedCaches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941874.aspx) element, or by passing in the setting when you create your `MemoryCache` instance via the `NameValueCollection` passed into the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.memorycache.aspx) by putting an entry in the collection with a key of [cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.configuration.memorycacheelement.cachememorylimitmegabytes.aspx) and a value of `10`.

Here is an example of the `namedCaches` configuration element:

```
<configuration>
  <system.runtime.caching>
    <memoryCache>
      <namedCaches>
        <add name="Default" 
          cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes="10" 
          physicalMemoryLimitPercentage="0"
          pollingInterval="00:05:00" />
      </namedCaches>
    </memoryCache>
  </system.runtime.caching>
</configuration>
```

And here is how you can configure the `MemoryCache` during creation:

```
//Create a name / value pair for properties
var config = new NameValueCollection();
config.Add("pollingInterval", "00:05:00");
config.Add("physicalMemoryLimitPercentage", "0");
config.Add("cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes", "10");

//instantiate cache
var cache = new MemoryCache("CustomCache", config);
```

This [blog post](http://shujaatsiddiqi.blogspot.com/2011/03/wpf-configuring-systemruntimecachingmem.html) details just about all of the ways to configure the `MemoryCache` object, and some examples were adapted from this source.

Comment: When does this size limit get evaluated? When adding a new cache entry or only during the polling interval?

Comment: @manipurea async according to the `pollingInterval` and in concery=t with some complex gymnastics you can see if you take ILSpy to it

Answer (score 11):

You can do this in configuration... for example...

```
<system.runtime.caching>
   <memoryCache>
      <namedCaches>
         <add name="Default"
              cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes="52"
              physicalMemoryLimitPercentage="40"
              pollingInterval="00:04:01" />
      </namedCaches>
   </memoryCache>
</system.runtime.caching>
```

To do this in code see... [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.memorycache.aspx)

Comment: Cool!! Can you do it in code too? Do you know how to tell how big the cache is?

Comment: You should be able to as it takes the config items in it constructor... as a a name value collection.

Comment: You know... I tried all this a while back & couldn't get it working... I'm not sure why I left myself a note to post asking about this. I will further investigate.

Comment: Why are both cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes & physicalMemoryPercentage used together? I would have thought it logical to use one or the other.

Answer (score 8):

It seems at this time the maximum amount of memory allocated for the cache can not be enforced. See this post for further reference: [MemoryCache does not obey memory limits in configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895956/memorycache-strangeness)