# LRU (Least Recently Used) algorithm in MemoryCache

Tags: c#, caching

I am using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache and I want to remove the Least Recently Used when the cache reaches the maximum number of entries.
Here's my code,

```
public class MemoryCacheManagement
{
    private MemoryCache Cache { get; set; }
    
    public MemoryCacheRepository()
        {
            Cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions
            {
                SizeLimit = 5
            });
        }
    
    public void SetValue<T>(string key, T value)
        {
            Cache.Set(key, value, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                .SetSize(1)
            );
        }
}
```

This is my test

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    var cache = new MemoryCacheManagement();

    User[]? users = new User[]
    {
                new User { Id = 1, Name = "User1", Age = 20 },
                new User { Id = 2, Name = "User2", Age = 21 },
                new User { Id = 3, Name = "User3", Age = 22 },
                new User { Id = 4, Name = "User4", Age = 21 },
                new User { Id = 5, Name = "User5", Age = 22 },
                new User { Id = 6, Name = "User6", Age = 21 },
                new User { Id = 1, Name = "User1", Age = 20 },
                new User { Id = 7, Name = "User7", Age = 22 },
                new User { Id = 2, Name = "User2", Age = 21 },
                new User { Id = 3, Name = "User3", Age = 22 },
                new User { Id = 2, Name = "User2", Age = 21 },
                new User { Id = 3, Name = "User3", Age = 22 }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
    {
        cache.SetValue(users[i].Id.ToString(), users[i]);
    }
}
```

Is the a way to setup the `MemoryCacheEntryOptions` so the least recently used entry to be removed?

Thanks

Comment: Use a list instead of an array.  Lists are easier to remove an item.

Comment: @jdweng AFAIK the problem is not in the array (which just holds test data) but in the memory cache behaviour.

Comment: It seems that you will have to implement your own `ObjectCache`. Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62399035/2501279) answer?

Comment: I can't see how the LRU is being removed in the code above

Comment: @GuruStron : The OP want to remove items from the array : User[]? users = new User[]

Comment: I want to remove the least recently used from the cache not from the array

Comment: @jdweng no, OP want's cache to be cleared using LRU algorithm.