# IMemeoryCache: how to set the cache size?

Tags: caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When using the `IMemoryCache` interface in `ASP.Net Core MVC`, is there any way to limit the size of the cache? for example to 1Gb only? If so how can this be done? I browsed the methods of this middleware, but could not find anything.

Comment: What are you hosting the application on? [Here's an IIS solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5547105/4270650)